# Inserting access data into .CSV and data is inserted with time

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert data from Access to CSV file. In access file, I have a RecordingDate field. whenever I insert the RecordingDate field, time is autimatically appened in CSV file. for e.g. In my access file I have this:

```
3/2/2020
```

and in CSV file, this same field shows as :

```
3/2/2020  12:00:00 AM
```

Below is my code in C#:

```
var textWriter = new StreamWriter(_configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettings:CSVFile"));
            var writer = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(textWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AccessConnection")))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select *  from RecsCD", connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);

                   }
  while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount))
                    {
                        writer.WriteField(reader.GetFieldValue<object>(i));
                    }

                    writer.NextRecord();
                }
            }
```

any help in removing the time part will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
 foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)) {
  var value = reader.GetFieldValue <object> (i); // put it in a variable
  DateTime temp;

  // check if the field you read is datetime
  if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out temp)) {
   // if so then format it -- you can also apply some sort of formatting too
   writer.WriteField(temp.ToShortDateString());
  } else {
   // if not datetime, then write whatever the value is
   writer.WriteField(value);
  }
 }
```